# How can Keras Conv1D towers be concatenated in an inception module?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I have data of 18 features and 2 classes. I've got a working Keras convolutional network for this data and it works just fine. Now I'm trying to get an inception module network set up for the same data. When I try to make this, something goes wrong at the concatenate step.

I've tried concatenating the towers of `Conv1D` layers as I did for the `Conv2D` layers but this has not worked.

The working simple convolutional model is as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(32, (5), strides = (1), input_shape = (18, 1), activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(pool_size = (2), strides = (2)))
model.add(Conv1D(32, (3), strides = (1), input_shape = (18, 1), activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(300,                                            activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dense(300,                                            activation = 'tanh'))
model.add(Dropout(rate = 0.5))
model.add(Dense(num_classes,                                    activation = 'softmax', name = "preds"))
model.compile(loss = "categorical_crossentropy", optimizer = "nadam", metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

Now, the inception model, with three convolutional towers, is as follows:

```
inputs  = Input((18, 1))
tower_1 = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=(3), strides=(2), padding='same')(inputs)
tower_1 = Conv1D(32, (1), activation='tanh', border_mode='same')(tower_1)
tower_2 = Conv1D(32, (1), activation='tanh', border_mode='same')(inputs)
tower_2 = Conv1D(32, (3), activation='tanh', border_mode='same')(tower_2)
tower_3 = Conv1D(32, (1), activation='tanh', border_mode='same')(inputs)
tower_3 = Conv1D(32, (5), activation='tanh', border_mode='same')(tower_3)
x       = concatenate([tower_1, tower_2, tower_3], axis=3)
x       = Flatten()(x)
x       = Dense(50, activation='tanh')(x)
preds   = Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax', name='preds')(x)
model   = Model(input=inputs, output=preds)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='nadam', metrics  =['accuracy'])
```

When I try to run the latter, I get the following output and I'm not sure why:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-22-1dbf3d2822ae> in <module>()
          6 tower_3 = Conv1D(32, (1), activation='tanh', border_mode='same')(inputs)
          7 tower_3 = Conv1D(32, (5), activation='tanh', border_mode='same')(tower_3)
    ----> 8 x       = concatenate([tower_1, tower_2, tower_3], axis=3)
          9 x       = Flatten()(x)
         10 #x       = Dense(50, activation='tanh')(x)

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/merge.py in concatenate(inputs, axis, **kwargs)
        639         A tensor, the concatenation of the inputs alongside axis `axis`.
        640     """
    --> 641     return Concatenate(axis=axis, **kwargs)(inputs)
        642 
        643 

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, **kwargs)
        429                                          'You can build it manually via: '
        430                                          '`layer.build(batch_input_shape)`')
    --> 431                 self.build(unpack_singleton(input_shapes))
        432                 self.built = True
        433 

    /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/merge.py in build(self, input_shape)
        346         shape_set = set()
        347         for i in range(len(reduced_inputs_shapes)):
    --> 348             del reduced_inputs_shapes[i][self.axis]
        349             shape_set.add(tuple(reduced_inputs_shapes[i]))
        350         if len(shape_set) > 1:

    IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

Friends, comrades, can you guide me on why this might be happening and on how it might be fixed?

Comment: Do you have 3 axes? What is the shape of tower_1, tower_2, etc. I think you should concatenate along axis=2.

Comment: @dgumo Ah that was it. Thanks a million! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Conv1D, the usual input and output shapes have the format `(batch_dim, width, channels)`, so merging with `axis=3` goes out of bounds, this would be the value that you use with Conv2D, which has 4-dimensional inputs and outputs.

So the simple solution is to use `axis=2` here:

```
x       = concatenate([tower_1, tower_2, tower_3], axis=2)
```

Comment: Magic! Thanks for that, hombre. And thanks for the brisk explanation of what the problem was.